# HTML Static Link Color Changes Depending on App or Browser Theme

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am building an application using nodejs with nodemailer which sends a confirmation link to user's email. I have added a simple HTML with inline styles to display text and a button. I want the button's text to be always white color, but the app/browser changes the color of the link even though i have set the color of all links to white.

Code:

```
<html>
        <head>
          <style>
            .button {
              background-color: #129575;
              border: none;
              color: #ffffff;
              padding: 15px 32px;
              text-align: center;
              text-decoration: none;
              display: inline-block;
              font-size: 16px;
              margin: 4px 2px;
              cursor: pointer;
              border-radius: 24px;
            }
            a, a:link, a:visited {
              color: #ffffff;
              text-decoration: none;
            }
          </style>
        </head>
        <body>
          <div>
            <div style={{ width: 500 }}>
              <div>
                <h2>Confirm Your Email Address</h2>
                <p>
                  Tap the button below to confirm your email address. If you didn't create an account with our app, you can safely delete this email.
                </p>
                <a href=${link} class="button">
                    Confirm Email
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </body>
      </html>
```

the links comes with greenish color as it is supposed to be but the link color is black (when i am in dark mode) and white when i am in light mode. If i reverse the color (set the link's color to black, everything will be vice-versa).

How to set the link's color to always be white?

[image: example]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this with blenders and help [from this post](https://www.emailonacid.com/blog/article/email-development/12_things_you_must_know_when_developing_for_gmail_and_gmail_mobile_apps-2/#gmail_tip5).

Basically, my code looks like this now:

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta name="color-scheme" content="light only">
    <style>
      .myLink {
        color:#fff;display: 
        inline-block;border-radius: 24px;
        font-size: 16px;
        margin: 4px 2px;
        padding: 15px 32px;
        text-align: center;
        border: none;
        text-decoration: none;
        background:#129575; 
        background-image:linear-gradient(#129575,#129575);
      }
      u + .body .gmail-blend-screen { background:#000; mix-blend-mode:screen; }
      u + .body .gmail-blend-difference { background:#000; mix-blend-mode:difference; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body class="body">
    <h2>Confirm Your Email Address</h2>
    <p>
      Tap the button below to confirm your email address. If you didn't create an account with our app, you can safely delete this email.
    </p>
    <a href=${link} class="myLink">
      <div class="gmail-blend-screen">
          <div class="gmail-blend-difference">
              Confirm Email
          </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Now the text is changing from black to white depending on the theme and the button is always set to my color with white text inside.